# Sorting a dict of dict in python

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and I have a doubt

I have a dict of dict which looks like

```
{"boy" : { "NN" : 3 ,"VB" : 3, "PP" : 2 } }
```

In case of a conflict of values as shown in the example above , I want to sort the internal dict based on their keys in descending order. The answer should look like :

```
{"boy" : {"VB" : 3, "NN" : 3, "PP":2} }
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Dicts are unordered and cannot be sorted. Use OrderedDict instead

Comment: You only see that ordering when you print the dictionary. It's stored in memory unordered, because it's a hash table. Look up "printing dict in sorted order" if you want to see it displayed differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: You only want the inner dict sorted "in the case of conflicting values?" This suggests you are collecting votes. Is the decending order given in your example desired output a case of VB > NN > PP or is that the value 3 has more keys than the value 2?

Answer (score 2):

Use an `OrderedDict`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
outer_dict = {"boy" : { "NN" : 3 ,"VB" : 3, "AA" : 2 } }
for key in outer_dict:
    inner_dict = outer_dict[key]
    outer_dict[key] = OrderedDict(sorted(inner_dict.items(), reverse=True))
```

Comment: This solution given, I think it is more likely you want to be using some other data structure. What is your intended use?

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the inner dictionaries like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dict_of_dict = {"boy" : { "NN" : 3 ,"VB" : 3, "AA" : 2 } }

# sort inner dictionaries by descending key values
dict_of_dict = {key: OrderedDict(sorted(inner_dict.items(), reverse=True))
                    for key, inner_dict in dict_of_dict.items()}

print(dict_of_dict) # -> {'boy': OrderedDict([('VB', 3), ('NN', 3), ('AA', 2)])}
```